# OpenVPN Client routing table fault: "route add 181.122.233.210/32 via 0.0.0.0 RTNETLINK answers: No such device"

Tags: linux, openvpn

I am user of openvpn , I have very lowskill with it. My Internet Supplier have a crazy server-network . So I am using  pppd program to establish connection to internet , and then I am starting the openvpn (via 'root') , with an option 
`openvpn --config /path_to_the_openvpn_server_config_file.openvpn` 
after that I had been usually receiving a some crazy stuff through TTY output , but seems all things is going well before that happens 
`/sbin/ip route add 176.126.237.214/32 via 0.0.0.0
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
2015 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2`
 :( - and all is turns to the fallout...  So, do anybody knows what are that crazy things is??? Thanx fo help.

P.S.  And yeah myPC has an `iptables`-program, but seem problems is out there because no difference in the `DROP` packages either with a `openvpn` or without ;/ And yeah , i poor English, sorry. .

____________added_______________
*.openvpn - OpenVPN , client-side config.file

`client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote 176.126.237.214 53
remote euro214.vpnbook.com 53
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 10
redirect-gateway`

---------------------added--------------------------------------

Workaround: OPENVPN seems to discard default route in PPP device , :/ . Or maybe that`s a topology problem , as I know PPPD using topology p2p (maybe :D ) , and openvpn server want from the my client net30 topology.

```
ip route replace default via NN.NN.NN.NN dev ppp[n]
```

where is NN.NN.NN.NN - ur default route stuff from `ip route show` , numbers after "peer" word. n - ur device number (is a name , generally)  . 
After this things , OPENVPN starst connecting fine , but no the traffic cant run through it , except  Tor budle browser :( , 
What is that mean ??? O_O

------------------added-----------------------

I understand why Tor bundle browser still working , even when OpenVPN is in job, that because Tor Browser using n80 , and n443 ports , and my OpenVPN client messing up with a n53 port...

But the problem is still exist - no traffic can go through OpenVPN tunnel over PPP connection. :(

Comment: could you post your openvpn config file?

Comment: `client`
`dev tun0`
`proto udp`
`remote 176.126.237.214 53`
`remote euro214.vpnbook.com 53`
`resolv-retry infinite`
`nobind`
`persist-key`
`persist-tun`
`auth-user-pass`
`comp-lzo`
`verb 3`
`cipher AES-128-CBC`
`fast-io`
`pull`
`route-delay 10`
`redirect-gateway`

Comment: Please don't add config in a comment - instead, you should edit your question to include it.

Comment: zzzzzzzzzz done.